# 3 variable symmetric inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Show that for positive reals $a,b,c$, 
$\frac{a^2}{b+c}+\frac{b^2}{c+a}+\frac{c^2}{a+b}\geq \frac{3a^3+3b^3+3c^3}{2a^2+2b^2+2c^2}$

What I did was WLOG $a+b+c=1$ (since the inequality is homogenous)
Then I substituted into the LHS to get $\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a^2}{1-a}\geq \frac{3a^3+3b^3+3c^3}{2a^2+2b^2+2c^2}$. Now I'm not sure if I should clear the denominators and expand and try to use Muirhead+Schur? (Clearing the denominators seems quite tedious)?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Your inequality is equivalent to: (use WolframAlpha [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*%28a%5E2%29*%28c%2Ba%29*%28a%2Bb%29*%28a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%29%2B2*%28b%5E2%29*%28b%2Bc%29*%28a%2Bb%29*%28a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%29%2B2*%28c%5E2%29*%28b%2Bc%29*%28c%2Ba%29*%28a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%29) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%28a%5E3%2Bb%5E3%2Bc%5E3%29%28a%2Bb%29%28b%2Bc%29%28c%2Ba%29), or calculate yourself):

$$\sum_{\text{sym}}a^6+2\sum_{\text{sym}}a^5b+ 2\sum_{\text{sym}}a^4b^2+ \sum_{\text{sym}}a^4bc+2\sum_{\text{sym}}a^3 b^3+\sum_{\text{sym}}a^3 b^2c$$

Comment: $$\ge 3\sum_{\text{sym}}a^5b+3\sum_{\text{sym}} a^4b^2+3\sum_{\text{sym}}a^4bc$$

I.e.

$$\sum_{\text{sym}}a^6+2\sum_{\text{sym}}a^3b^3+\sum_{\text{sym}}a^3b^2c\ge \sum_{\text{sym}}a^5b+\sum_{\text{sym}}a^4b^2+2\sum_{\text{sym}}a^4bc$$

Try using Schur, AM-GM, Muirhead (see [here](https://www.tjhsst.edu/~2010bhamrick/files/dumbassing.pdf)). Muirhead doesn't directly solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your inequalitiy is equivalent to
$$\left(a^3-2 a b c+b^3+c^3\right) \left(2 a^3-a^2 b-a^2 c-a b^2-a c^2+2 b^3-b^2
   c-b c^2+2 c^3\right)\geq 0$$
since $$a^3+b^3+c^3\geq 3abc>2abc$$ is the first factor positive,
and
$$2(a^3+b^3+c^3)\geq ab(a+b)+ac(a+c)+bc(b+c)$$
since $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)\geq ab(a+b)$ etc is the second factor also positive.